# "The specified session ID does not exist or is no longer active" Exception from selenium on Edge browser,

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium

I am trying to get data from like 100 sites using selenium and I have got the addresses stored in a table.
While iterating through them, I am creating a driver, navigating to the site getting the data and then closing the driver using `driver.Quit();`. While doing all these, I am getting a couple of exceptions and errors, such as 
1. If I refresh the page, It says the  Access denied, dont have permission to access this site on this server.
2. The Element is loaded but gets stale.
3. Timed out after 60 seconds .
4. Element not found in the current frame or window.
5. The session Id is no longer valid.

I am able to find the respective exceptionHandler for all the exceptions but the last one is inconclusive. I am unable to ascertain why this is caused as subsequent executions are working fine.
This is the log Trace that I am getting

`The specified session ID does not exist or is no longer active.`

`at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary 2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteNavigator.GoToUrl(String url)
   at WebApplication6.Controllers.MongoController.getIndicesDetails()`

Any guidance would be appreciated .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in driver instances which are still alive and depending on browser,different exception would come.
So instead of using `driver.Quit()`, using `driver.Dispose()` would clean the instance completely.